# How to merge two dataframes with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two pandas dataframes with stock prices. The dates on the files do not match. I need to merge the two dataframes, leaving the missing data as blank. For example:

```
>>> dfA                 >>> dfB
$Date         $AAA      $Date         $BBB
08/09/2017    50.21     08/09/2017    142.22
09/09/2017    50.25     11/09/2017    142.25
10/09/2017    50.20     12/09/2017    142.65
```

And the output I need is:

```
$Date         $AAA         $BBB
08/09/2017    50.21        142.22
09/09/2017    50.25        N/A
10/09/2017    50.20        N/A
11/09/2017    N/A          142.25
12/09/2017    N/A          142.65
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an `outer` merge. By default `merge` will use overlapping columns as the join keys, so in this case you don't need to specify `on='$Date'`

```
dfA.merge(dfB, how='outer')
```

#### Output:

```
        $Date   $AAA    $BBB
0  08/09/2017  50.21  142.22
1  09/09/2017  50.25     NaN
2  10/09/2017  50.20     NaN
3  11/09/2017    NaN  142.25
4  12/09/2017    NaN  142.65
```